# Induction principle on well ordered set

Tags: logic, set-theory, induction, well-orders

I'm new and very grateful this site exists. If I do something wrong, feel free to tell me.

I have to prove the following:

Let $S$ be a subset of a well ordered set $L$ with the conditions:

a) $0_L \in S$

b) If $x \in S$ then $x+1 \in S$

c) If $l$ is a nonzero limit element  of $L$ and $L_{<x} \subseteq S$, then $l\in S$

Prove that $L=S$.

I think I have to take an element of L randomly and prove it is in S. If it is $0_L$, we are done. Suppose it is $x+1$ for a certain $x$ in L. Then it is enough that x is in L by (b), but how to show x is in L?

Maybe splitting the case it is a limit element or a succesor of a certain y in L?

Can someone explain me please? I'm looking at this for days...

**Edit:** My definition of a limit element is an element that is not a successor of some other element.

Comment: It is given that $S \subseteq L$. To show $L = S$, show that $L \subseteq S$. That is to say, if I have an element $x \in L$, show that $x \in S$.

Comment: Yeah, but how? :)

Comment: Well, either $x = 0_L$, or $x \ne 0_L$. In the former case, (a) shows that $x \in S$. In the latter case, can you show that $x$ is a limit element of $L$ and $\{ y \in L | y < x \} \subseteq S$?

Comment: if x is not 0_L, then it hasn't to be a limit element I thought?

Comment: Since you are grateful that this site exists, I would like to point out that this community will be grateful if you show what _you_ have tried. Even if you are hopelessly stuck, adding more context (how you arrived at this problem) and if you have any thoughts on how to attack this problem to get answers. Please [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4677025/edit) to include the changes. For more information, please see [How to ask a Good Question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question)

Comment: is it better now?

Comment: What is your definition for "limit element of $L$"?

Comment: Every element that is not a successor

Comment: so that you can  not write as an x+1 with x in L

Comment: Do you mean, every element that does *not* have a successor is a limit element?

Comment: @K.Jiang I think the definition is correct as user236 has written it - a limit element is an element that is not a successor of another element.

Comment: That makes sense. So in other words, there does not exist $y \in L$ such that $x = y + 1$.

Comment: @user236 I hope you don't mind that I took the liberty of transferring your definition into the body of the question

Comment: @K.Jiang Yep, agreed

Comment: Thank you!!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you haven't yet used the fact that $L$ is *well-ordered* in your solution attempt! That's the reason why you're stuck.

I would set up the proof like this.

Suppose, for contradiction, that $S$ is not the whole of $L$. Then $L \setminus S$ is a non-empty subset of $L$. Since $L$ is well-ordered, all non-empty subsets of $L$ contain a minimal element. In particular, the subset $L \setminus S$ contains a minimal element $m$.

To phrase this another way, if $S$ is not the whole of $L$, then there must exists an element $m \in L$ such that:

- $m \notin S$.
- If $x < m$, then $x \in S$.

Now your task is to derive a contradiction from this.

I suggest you consider three cases separately.

- Case 1: $m = 0_L$.
- Case 2: $m$ is a successor element, i.e. there exists an $x \in L$ such that $m = x + 1$.
- Case 3: $m$ is a non-zero limit element, i.e. $m \neq 0_L$, and $m \neq x + 1 $ for all $x \in L$.

You need to: (i) convince yourself that these three cases cover all the possibilities, and (ii) derive a contradiction in *each* of these three cases.

Comment: A very big thank you!!